# Error in \sum in state

Tags: errors, subscripts, superscripts

I use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\date{\today}
\title{Some Title}


\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    bla afdsdjkh
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Caption}
        \textbf{INPUT:} Some input\\
        \textbf{OUTPUT:} Some Output
        \begin{algorithmic}
       \State Function $UpdateNodes($x$)$:
       \State   Set $AED_i$ = $\sum_{j=1}^{n}$  $DM_i_j$ / $n$  
                \end{algorithmic}
            \end{algorithm} 
        \end{document}
```

Although I get the required result for the line:

```
\State  Set $AED_i$ = $\sum_{j=1}^{n}$  $DM_i_j$ / $n$
```

I get an error message:

```
"Double subscript. ...ate Set $AED_i$ = $\sum_{j=1}^{n}$ $DM_i_"
```

Why do I get it? and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should type `$\mathit{AED}_{i}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathit{DM}_{i_j}/n$`, not going in and out from math mode.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps, instead of `$DM_i_j$` you need to type `$DM_{i_j}$` or `${DM_i}_j$` depending of what you have in mind.

Comment: ...or `$D_{ij}$`...